# How to find custom post type category name & category ID

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I was try to find out the custom post type **category name & category ID**. But I am failed where is my problem using following script. I am unable to find out any one could help me.

```
$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'manual',
          'posts_per_page'   => -1,
          'taxonomy' => 'manual_cat',
      );
      

      $posts = new WP_Query($args);
      $usermanual  = [];
      if ($posts->have_posts()):
          while ($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post();
             
           
              $usermanual[] = array(
                  'ID'    => get_the_ID(),
                  'title' => get_the_title(get_the_ID()),
                  'content' => get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID()), 
                   'slug'  => get_post_field('post_name', get_the_ID()),
                   'Note'  => get_field('_wp_footnotes', get_the_ID()),
                   'category' => get_post_field('cat_ID', get_the_ID()), 
                 
              );
          endwhile;
      endif;
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287501/how-to-list-custom-taxonomy-categories/287504

Comment: i saw this post, I cant see the category name & category ID.

Comment: $terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'manual_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);

// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    // Run a loop and print them all
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
        </a><?php
    }
} (run this code on your files so u got it your category list with category link)

Comment: You cant get post category with get_post_field() . https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `get_post_field()` wont return taxonomy post terms.
You should use `get_the_terms()`

Your loop should look like this

```
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
if ($posts->have_posts()):
    while ($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post();

        $post_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'manual_cat');
        $usermanual[] = array(
            'ID'    => get_the_ID(),
            'title' => get_the_title(get_the_ID()),
            'content' => get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID()),
            'slug'  => get_post_field('post_name', get_the_ID()),
            'Note'  => get_field('_wp_footnotes', get_the_ID()),
            'category' => $post_terms
        );
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($usermanual); // Debug results
        echo '</pre>';
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: That is working thank Martin Mirchev

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
              $category = get_the_category()[0];

              $usermanual[] = array(
                  'ID'    => get_the_ID(),
                  'title' => get_the_title(get_the_ID()),
                  'content' => get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID()), 
                   'slug'  => get_post_field('post_name', get_the_ID()),
                   'Note'  => get_field('_wp_footnotes', get_the_ID()),
                   'category_name' => $category['name'],
                   'category_id' => $category['term_id']
                 
              );
```

This assumes there is only one category. For custom taxonomies use [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/).

Comment: I dont get category name & id